# Angular + ASP.NET MVC4 Session always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I am developing a SPA in angular which is running within nginx server and an ASP.NET MVC4 web app that runs in IIS server provides some API functions to angular app. As soon as user logins some data need to be kept in httpsession( Assume I don't want to use angular's session storage). But the session is always returns null, even I stored some data after successful login. Please have a look on some of the necessary code.

**authservice.js**

```
login: function (email, password) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     $http({
          url: global.API_URL + '/Auth/Login',
          method: 'POST',
                data: { email: email, password: encodeURIComponent(password)}
   }).then(function (response) {
       if (response.data.code == 0) {
          //If success go to home
});
```

**AuthController.js**

```
    [ActionName("Login")]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index(string email, string password)
    {
    CustResponse response = new CustResponse ();
    //Get the logged in user data
     User user = userService.GetUser(email);   

    //Get the hash 
    string hash = PasswordUtil.CreatePasswordHash(user.Salt, password);

    //Custom membership provider
    CustMembershipProvider provider = new CustMembershipProvider();
    bool isValid = provider.ValidateUser(email, hash); 

//Store the user token into the session
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["TOKEN"] = //Some token value;

    //if valid send response code 0
    response.code = 0;
    response.message = "Success";
    response.data = isValid ;

    return Json(response);
    }
```

The token is getting stored into the session as i can see it in the session object when I am in AuthController.

**AwmsMembershipProvider.cs**

```
 public class CustMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        public override bool ValidateUser(string email, string hash)
        {
            bool isValid = false;
            using (var db = new AwmsContext())
            {
               User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Email == email);
               if (user != null && user.PasswordHash != null &&            user.PasswordHash.Equals(hash))
              {
                  isValid = true;
               }
            }
            return isValid;
        }
```

**WebConfig.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AWMS-20160710224309;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AWMS-20160710224309.mdf" />
    <add name="AwmsContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/awms.csdl|res://*/awms.ssdl|res://*/awms.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=AWMS;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="LogFilePath" value="./App_Data/Config/Log.xml" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="20" />
    </authentication>    
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="AwmsMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AwmsMembershipProvider" type="Awms.Dal.Provider.AwmsMembershipProvider" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="EmblaRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="EmblaRoleProvider" type="Awms.Dal.Provider.AwmsRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="20" cookieless="false">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
       <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <clear />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:8085" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Once the user is logged in he's being redirected to home page and he need to access some of the previously stored session variables from another controller.

```
 public JsonResult GetRoles()
        {
               String token = (String)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["TOKEN"];
.....
}
```

When I am doing so it's always null. Am I doing anything wrong here. Please feel free to provide your valuable ideas

Comment: I see no code where that particular session key is actually *set*, or really where anything at all is being done with the session before you attempt to retrieve a value from it.

Comment: Sorry it was there but due to format issue it might not get highlighted to you. Anyhow it's available now

Comment: Did your web.config get pasted incorrectly?  It doesn't look correct.

Comment: I didn't provide you the whole web.config. If you want I can provide. Note that I put those dots

Comment: Yeah I noticed.  I just bring it up because the `<profile>` and `<membership>` nodes don't look closed off properly.  Just double checking that it wasn't a bad paste.

Comment: Now it contains full web.config

Comment: I don't see anything overtly incorrect. Are either of these controllers inheriting from `ApiController`?

Comment: It's getting inherited from System.Web.Mvc.Controller as // public class AuthController : Controller

Comment: When i debug the login c# code System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false, even after calling the custom membership provider's  validate method. Will that be a problem?

Comment: Also need to know as angular web app doesn't reside on the same IIS. Will that be a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

looks you need to enable cookies.  see details on below artical

https://gregorybeamer.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/session-and-cookies-in-asp-net-mvc-oh-my/